# Define a function based on a relation in Coq

Tags: coq

I'm working on a theory in which there is a relation C defined as

```
Parameter Entity: Set.    
Parameter C : Entity -> Entity -> Entity -> Prop.
```

The relation C is a relation of composition of some entities. Instead of `C z x y`, I want to be able to write `x o y = z`. So I have two questions:

- I think I should define a "function" (the word is perhaps not the right one) named fC that takes x and y and returns z. This way, I could use it in the Notation. But I don't know how to define this "function". Is it possible?
- I find that I can use the command `Notation` to define an operator. Something like `Notation "x o y" := fC x y.`. Is this the good way to do it?

I tried `Notation "x o y" := exists u, C u x y.` but it didn't work. Is there a way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your relation `C` has the property that, given `x` and `y`, there is a unique `z` such that `C z x y`, you cannot view it as representing a full-fledged function the way you suggest. This is why the notion of a relation is needed in that case.

As for defining a notation for the relation property, you can use:

```
Notation "x 'o y" := (exists u, C u x y) (at level 10).
```

Note the `'` before the `o` to help the parser handle the notation and the parentheses after the `:=` sign. The level can be changed to suit your parsing preferences.

Comment: I thought about it, but I forgot to mention it. There is an axiom of uniqueness in the theory.

Comment: If you don't have an explicit, constructive way to define `fC`, you can always add another axiom, as suggested by Pierre. A simple version could be:: `Axiom functionalC : exists fC, forall x y z, C x y z <-> fC x y = z`. Then you can use that in your proofs to go back and forth between the functional and relational points of view.
`.

Comment: In [Coq FAQ](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/The-Logic-of-Coq#axioms) you have a useful list of axioms which can safely added to Coq. _In general_, admitting a new ad-hoc axiom may make a development inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

If you define `x 'o y` as a proposition, you will lose the intuition of `o` being a binary operation on `Entity` (*i.e*  `x` o `y` should have type `Entity`).

You may write some variation like

```
Notation "x 'o y '= z" := (unique (fun t => C t x y)) (at level 10).
```

Otherwise, If your relation satisfies:

```
Hypothesis C_fun: forall x y,  {z : Entity | unique  (fun t => C t x y) z}.
```

then you may define:

```
Notation "x 'o y" := (proj1_sig (C_fun x y)) (at level 10).
Check fun a b: Entity =>  a 'o b.
```

Otherwise (if you have only have a weaker version of `C_fun`, with `exists`instead of `sig`) and accept to use classical logic and axioms), you may use the `Epsilon` operator
https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.ClassicalEpsilon.html